# Android app not compatible for Android SDK built for x86

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've successfully upload android app based on xamarin forms in google play store, it shows the list of my real devices that are compatible but it also shows that all my emulators are not compatible with it. When I debug it from visual studio it runs on my emulator. Now that it's in google play I want to try it in my emulator since I don't currently have my physical device I can't install it due to compatibility. It says not compatible to Android SDK built for x86.

Comment: Android apps can be built for armv7, arm64, and x86. I'd guess what you've built into your APK is just armv7. You'll need to build a different APK for x86 or change whatever settings you need to when building what you have to target both.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures

Comment: The APK will be larger the more platforms it needs to support. I don't use Xamarin, but Unity allows you to build multiple APK files with a single platform in each and each with a different versionCode so you can upload all of them to Google Play and a user will download the one they need. There may be similar functionality in Xamarin, or you can manually build them as long as you change the version code for each..

Comment: This says Google Play will create the splits for you but I don't think it splits on cpu architecture. It is possible it might though. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle

Comment: Thanks a lot @Retired Ninja